# insert / delete balise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a `p` tag in a `div` tag when I click a button, and also when I click on a `p` tag i want to delete the `p` tag I clicked on.

This is my Jquery:

```
$('#ajou').click(function(){
    alert( $('#skill').val());
    $('#skills').append('<p>'+$('#skill').val()+'</p>');
});

$("p").click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});`
```

And this is my HTML:

```
 <input type="text" id="skill" name="skill"> 
 <button id="ajou" name="ajou">Valide</button>
 <br><br>
 <div name="skills" id="skills"><p>hello</p> </div>
```

To be specific, when I click on the button `Valid` the text I entered in the input is add to my `<div>` but when I want to delete it I can't, only `<p>hello</p>` will remove it when I click on it.

Comment: Sorry, I can see english is not your native language but I cannot understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight change to your event handler to give it scope:

```
$('#skills').on('click', 'p', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

This allows the event to be bound to the skills and thus allow all paragraphs (p) to be removed from within that scope.  Binding to the p element only binds to the currently existing paragraphs (anywhere in the document) and not those added.

Comment: thanks you @Mark Schultheiss, it's work just fine thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Edited to full sample and to only remove `<p>` elements when clicked on. Works for both static and dynamic `<p>` elements.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="skill" name="skill"> 
<button id="ajou" name="ajou">Valide</button>
<br><br>
<div name="skills" id="skills"><p>hello</p> </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#ajou').click(function(){
    alert( $('#skill').val());
    $('#skills').append('<p>'+$('#skill').val()+'</p>');
});

$(document).on('click', '#skills p', function(events){   
    events.target.remove();
});
```

The latter is to bind the removal function to the parent element (#skills) simply because the children will be dynamically added later, so could not be bound beforehand. Once you catch the click on the parent it is possible to remove the clicked child `<p>` (targeted element).

Comment: This would remove the element with the `skills` id from the document if it was clicked.

Comment: Thats correct, Mark, thanks for pointing it out. I'll do something about it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div', {
    id: 'foo',
    name: 'anything',
    title: 'adding these attributes is not necessary',
    text: 'Waow, I am one sexy p tag'
}).appendTo($('.myDiv'));
```